# Programa en c++ sobre cadenas y subcadenas

Tags: c++, string

Buen día, tengo que desarrollar el siguiente problema[image: Como se muestra en la imagen]
Lo intente resolver con la función subString sin embargo con esta no me muestra las subcadenas con el orden que tiene la palabra :(
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
// Función para imprimir todas las subcadenas
void subString(char str[], int n) 
{
// Elija el punto de partida
for (int len = 1; len <= n; len++) 
{    
    // Elija el punto final
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - len; i++) 
    {
// Imprimir caracteres del actual punto de partida al final actual punto.
        int j = i + len - 1;            
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) 
            cout << str[k];            
        cout << endl;
     }
   }
 }
// Programa de controlador para probar la función anterior
int main() 
 {
  char str[10];
  printf("Coloca tu nombre \n");
  scanf ("%s",&str);
  subString(str, strlen(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Liliana Estefani, Puedes colgar el código aun que no funcione, para tener una base donde empezar a trabajar. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo el concepto de *subcadena* del enunciado, pero por lo que he podido ver se corresponde con seleccionar las letras de la palabra que coincidan con una representación binaria de un número de tantos bits como longitud tenga la palabra (eliminando repeticiones).

| Numero | binario → cabb |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `0000 →` |
| 1 | `0001 → b` |
| 2 | `0010 → b` |
| 3 | `0011 → bb` |
| 4 | `0100 → a` |
| 5 | `0101 → a b` |
| 6 | `0110 → ab` |
| 7 | `0111 → abb` |
| 8 | `1000 → c` |
| 9 | `1001 → c b` |
| 10 | `1010 → c b` |
| 11 | `1011 → c bb` |
| 12 | `1100 → ca` |
| 13 | `1101 → ca b` |
| 14 | `1110 → cab` |
| 15 | `1111 → cabb` |

El efecto es fácil de conseguir con un `std::set` (contenedor que no permite repeticiones) y un par de bucles:

```
auto getAllWords(const std::string &word)
{
    std::set<std::string> result;

    for (int indice = 0, fin = pow(2, word.length()); indice != fin; ++indice)
    {
        std::string palabra;

        for (int letra = 0, bit = 1; bit < fin; ++letra, bit <<= 1)
            if (bit & indice)
                palabra.push_back(word[letra]);

        result.insert(palabra);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLbsMgEDybr9imUgJKaqU9xk6kfEUPbVURjB1UDBaslUPVb3d55MmFZWaZ2R0xDC9Cc9NN07MyQo@NhFpZj07yfkduWECU6R4QifdP0XM87gjhI1roJO61freu8VRY4xE8NptNFoH5KRCM/JIioxLrO3oHTvpRY0VI0VoHVBkEZRolJGxhvYJWmVAM9kTfVhClSi1Nh0fKWHVpfNrGtgqWywwwUgS74n6KgWt@cDza3Hy0RMezzUFhKF6rVNQXudSQyboOdBAuCtUCjcgcrm7hnA3KYfTH7wMXPzQO@5EUvljyzZuWynjpkJ4/BKr4C6yTODpzTSNAccKeK0NTeGnonG4KPcUKm4fwZ3uDzg62t65Vws4Yu6Qg7BhXSAHGe/FpFtXNdR0Mp@kf)</kbd>, piensa que no funciona para palabras de más de 32 letras.

Comment: Muy buen análisis