# Generar subconjuntos de un conjunto = {a1,a2,....,an}

Tags: c++

En la escuela me han puesto la siguiente situacion:

Se me da un *array* `A = {a1, a2, a3, ..., an}`. La tarea es generar todos los *subconjuntos* de ese *array*.

**Nota** el array puede llegar a tener un tamaño de *3 a 10<sup>5</sup>*.

Por ejemplo:

`Entrada:`

```
3

1 2 3
```

`Salida`

```
{ }
{ 1 }
{ 2 }
{ 1 2 }
{ 3 }
{ 1 3 }
{ 2 3 }
{ 1 2 3 }
```

El codigo que use fue el siguiente:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;
int n;
vector<int> Arr;

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int a; cin>>a;
        Arr.push_back(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
        cout<<"{ ";
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i&(1<<j)){
                cout<<Arr[j]<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<"}\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quizás podrías poner lo que tienes hasta la fecha. Serviría como punto de partida para las respuestas

Comment: Muestra lo que has hecho hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer para que se entienda mas la pregunta

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/439730/programa-en-c-sobre-cadenas-y-subcadenas entra aqui

Comment: Seguro que ese código te va a generar, como dices, todas las secuencias posibles? Sin llegar a ejecutarlo ya veo que solo te puede generar una única secuencia

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? He ejecutado el código y hace lo que dices que debe hacer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RboMwDEXf/RURlaagahWsb02K1O/YJpSlaWs6DErCpqni21kKbFDyZPv6Ht/oun4@a911KyT92RwNk1g5b40qM5hmX0b7ymbQOKQzI1UaVyttmPNHJgDJMxIwLMnQZexgrYBeKBUSj2/Awgvo/EM5s9u5H9L5N/pLHhBY8SQW/YZG2ng08z7LaKhPleV3Iu5TgXJPAtfrEdzDg6TE4FDifxySbOrGXcJhfeVq5LYLYhKIPJWS4gVVV42XMrqxaEL@2YpgKySJ4sHRZzlxfLrzinihTMwQ7LV4D@w5esr2WI0x2jeK5h@wxjeWWCKg7botpPACW/gF "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")